# drawing automota states using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I really new to latex (~3 days of use) and I am trying to draw an automota for a problem that I am working... For some reason I am getting an error and my states all appears to be messed up. **Please the point of this is not for you to do my homework for me.** The solution I have is wrong any ways... I am just trying to see if I can properly draw the states. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}


\topmargin = 0.1in \textwidth=5.7in \textheight=8.6in

\oddsidemargin = 0.2in \evensidemargin = 0.2in


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    Theory of Computation, SPRING 2015 \\
    Homework Problems\\
\end{center}

\smallskip

\begin{enumerate}
    \item L has all strings w such that w does not contain 101

 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state,initial, accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
   \node[state](q_1) [below right=of q_1] {$q_1$};
    \path[->] 
    (q_0) 
       edge  node {0} (q_1)
        edge [loop above] node {1} ()
    (q_1) 
          edge [loop above] node {0} ();
\end{tikzpicture}

    \item L has all strings w such that w any string of 1's and 0's except 11 and 111
     \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state,initial, accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
   \node[state](q_1) [below right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
    \path[->] 
    (q_0) 
       edge  node {0} (q_1)
        edge [loop above] node {1} ()
    (q_1) edge [loop above] node {0} ();
\end{tikzpicture}

    \item L has all strings w such that w contains at least two 0's and at most one 1
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state,initial, accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
   \node[state](q_1) [below right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
    \path[->] 
    (q_0) 
       edge  node {0} (q_1)
        edge [loop above] node {1} ()
    (q_1) 
          edge [loop above] node {0} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}


\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would help if you clarify what you mean with "properly draw the states". What exactly is the desired output? By the way, not bad for a ~3 day user!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had

```
\node[state] (q_1) [below right=of q_1] {$q_1$};
```

but it should be

```
\node[state] (q_1) [below right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
```

You need to use already existing node names to relatively place other nodes. You were trying to use `q_1` to place `q_1` and that was triggering the error.

You complete code (reduced):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    Theory of Computation, SPRING 2015 \\
    Homework Problems\\
\end{center}

\smallskip

\begin{enumerate}
    \item L has all strings w such that w does not contain 101

 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state,initial, accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
   \node[state] (q_1) [below right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
    \path[->] 
    (q_0) 
       edge  node {0} (q_1)
        edge [loop above] node {1} ()
    (q_1) 
          edge [loop above] node {0} ();
\end{tikzpicture}

    \item L has all strings w such that w any string of 1's and 0's except 11 and 111
     \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state,initial, accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
   \node[state](q_1) [below right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
    \path[->] 
    (q_0) 
       edge  node {0} (q_1)
        edge [loop above] node {1} ()
    (q_1) edge [loop above] node {0} ();
\end{tikzpicture}

    \item L has all strings w such that w contains at least two 0's and at most one 1
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state,initial, accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
   \node[state](q_1) [below right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
    \path[->] 
    (q_0) 
       edge  node {0} (q_1)
        edge [loop above] node {1} ()
    (q_1) 
          edge [loop above] node {0} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]